# How to leave textbox instead of send value to the database in windows forms using c#?

Tags: c#

I developing a windows application so, I have only some textbox values send to 
  database remaining `textbox` values send 0 if the user does not enter any value.

I know how to send my approach is like that :

```
int x;
if(textbox1.Text!="")
{
 x=int.Parse(textbox1.Text);
}
else
{
 x=0;
}
```

Now I send a value to the database through my business logic something..
  something.

This is my approach so I have a 35 textbox's in my project I want only 5 
  textbox's is required fields remaining are optional.

So is this correct approach to set values to 0 if the user doesn't enter any
  value? otherwise give me your valuable suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> So Is this correct approach to set values to 0 if the user doesn't enter any value?

Zero is a concrete, specific value. If you want to denote that the user did not use any value, use *null*.

An integer cannot store the value null, but a *nullable* integer can.

```
int? x = null;
```

Note that your database column must allow nulls for this to work.

Note that int.Parse() can throw an exception (if the input is not a number, e.g. `Hello`). It is better to use int.TryParse like this

```
int tmp;
bool valid = int.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out tmp);
x = valid ? (int?)tmp : null; // Assumes x is a nullable integer.
```

Comment: In this case we have to define number of variables because i have 35 textbox's so 35 fields we should define is there any problem @Eric J

Comment: tmp is it nullable value?because it shows an error local variable int tmp. There is no implicit conversion between int and <null> in your third line. i know x is a nullable type. @Eric thanks.

Comment: You are missing nullable type casting x=valid? (int?)tmp :null now it is working thanks @Eric

Comment: You can create a list or array of nullable int, or for that matter a `Dictionary<TextBox, int?>`. tmp is an integer in my example and works fine like that.

Comment: can you show me the array of nullable int? store multiple variable values thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use the [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) Method:

```
Int32.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out x);
```

However, if no value is provided, it may be better to use null values instead to your database.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Write the validation for all the 5 textboxes which are required. and for optional ones after the 5 textbox validation.

```
void AddZerotoText(Control con)
{
    foreach (Control c in con.Controls)
    {
        if (c is TextBox)
        {
            if(((TextBox)c).Text == "")
                ((TextBox)c).Text = "0";
        }
    }
}
```

So this will check the validation for first 5 textboxes which are required and then check for all the textboxes which are blank and will add `0` in the textbox.

Comment: Some of the textbox's have string in my case then is it work?

Comment: yes @Nag that is going to work as we are checking `if(((TextBox)c).Text == "")` that will not do the operation on the textboxes that does have any values.